# i'm trying to append text in Text file using servlet which gives an error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, file-io

well my directory structure is same eclipse based web application structure

[image]

through `resourceAsStream()` im able to read `admin.properties` file.
but i need to append this file too. 
how to read this file

because

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/res/admin.properties");
```

will give `FileNotFoundException` . please inform me why its not visible to the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(getServletContext().getRealPath("admin.properties"));
```

This should work for you.Please keep in mind if you are testing from Tomcat in Eclipse, it will not change the file in your workspace rather it edits the one in `wtpwebapps` which is default location where your Eclipse Tomcat instance will deploy the application in default settings.

*Assuming you are using Tomcat container.*

Comment: hi thanks for ur support , still get the problem the file not updating at all
i used following code 

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(getServletContext().getRealPath("admin.properties"),true);
  
  writer.append("this is new appended content 9/21/2015");
  writer.close();

Comment: are u running from eclipse ?

Comment: please create a war file and deploy in Tomcat (not from eclipse) and verify if its writing to the file.

Comment: sure will do it and thanks a lot for ur valuable support